# API get call not working in react native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, fetch-api

I am working on a react native app and trying to get data from and api.
while I am trying to get data the response is as below showing in debugger. if anyone knows fo fix this could please help me on this

---

code

```
  componentDidMount() {
 const {sessionkey} = this.props
    this.apii(sessionkey);
  }

  apii  = async (sessionkey) => { fetch(`url here`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    key: 'X-Frame-Options',
    value: 'SAMEORIGIN',
        sessionkey,
  },
 
})
  .then(r => {
    console.log(r)
    return response.json();
  }).then(json => console.warn(json))
  }
```

---

inside console

```
date: "Sun, 04 Sep 2022 06:24:56 GMT"
​​​
expires: "0"
​​​
pragma: "no-cache"
​​​
server: "cloudflare"
​​​
"x-content-type-options": "nosniff"
​​​
"x-frame-options": "DENY"
​​​
"x-powered-by": ""
​​​
"x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @AG api is not responding body response only the header and above 
"x-frame-options": "DENY" showing in header